# IIS 7 desktop icon cannot be renamed to “IIS Manager”

Tags: windows, iis, windows-7, desktop

If I take the IIS manager shortcut on my desktop, which is named "Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager" by default, and rename it to "IIS Manager", it sets the name right back. However, if I rename the shortcut to "IIS" or "Foo" or something else, it renames the shortcut correctly. What is this happening?

Note:
I did some more experimenting and found that even if you take the path *%windir%\system32\inetsrv\InetMgr.exe* and make a completely new shortcut, the same phenomenon still happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because, interestingly enough, the name of the shortcut is *already* "IIS Manager" - look at the name in the command prompt.

Explorer is changing the displayed name because of a `[LocalizedFileNames]` directive in the `desktop.ini` file:

`[LocalizedFileNames]`
`IIS Manager.lnk=@%SystemRoot%\system32\inetsrv\InetMgr.exe,-101`

Even more interestingly though, removing this entry doesn't display the real name of the file, even after restarting Explorer. Not sure if there's a way around it.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.

I was able to rename it to IIS[nullspace]Manager without any issue.  It looks the same as IIS Manager, but uses a nullspace instead of a space.

To type a nullspace, hold down the Alt key, while holding it down type 255 on the number pad, then release the alt key.  (You must use the number pad.  The numbers in the top row will not work)

Comment: Nice workaround! :)